# How to Add Visibility Keyframe on Collection?

Tags: keyframes, outliner, visibility

I have many animated objects with keyframes. I want to hide/ make visible all objects with one click or one keyframe? How I can do this?

In previous versions, I could easily add a keyframe in outliner with shortcut key <kbd>I</kbd> but now I can't.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181316 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185837 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/205895